# how to create google spreadsheet by any google user programatically in android

Tags: android, google-sheets

I have to make a demo for making Google Spreadsheet in android. I have gone through some links and have made a demo its working fine,but its working for only one credentials. I want that when user enters his/her credentials the Spreadsheet should be created in his/her Google drive. But right now when I am changing the credentials it says"Invalid Credentials" as shown in my logcat trace.

My code is as below, can any one please tell me what should i do for this issue?

**my code**

```
public void Create_SpreadSheet() {

            DocsService docsService = new DocsService("MySampleApplication-v3");
            try {
                docsService.setUserCredentials("abcd@gmail.com", "axxxxyy");
                URL GOOGLE_DRIVE_FEED_URL = new URL(
                        "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/");
                DocumentListEntry documentListEntry = new com.google.gdata.data.docs.SpreadsheetEntry();
                documentListEntry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct(et_en.getText()
                        .toString()));
                documentListEntry = docsService.insert(GOOGLE_DRIVE_FEED_URL,
                        documentListEntry);

            } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ServiceException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

**logcat**

```
01-06 17:02:37.247: W/System.err(15487):    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthException(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:660)
01-06 17:02:37.247: W/System.err(15487):    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthToken(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:560)
01-06 17:02:37.247: W/System.err(15487):    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.setUserCredentials(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:397)
01-06 17:02:37.247: W/System.err(15487):    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:364)
01-06 17:02:37.247: W/System.err(15487):    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:319)
01-06 17:02:37.247: W/System.err(15487):    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:303)
01-06 17:02:37.247: W/System.err(15487):    at com.amar.google_integration.Second_Class.Create_SpreadSheet(Second_Class.java:226)
01-06 17:02:37.257: W/System.err(15487):    at com.amar.google_integration.Second_Class$3.onClick(Second_Class.java:159)
01-06 17:02:37.257: W/System.err(15487):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:170)
01-06 17:02:37.257: W/System.err(15487):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-06 17:02:37.257: W/System.err(15487):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
01-06 17:02:37.257: W/System.err(15487):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
01-06 17:02:37.257: W/System.err(15487):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 17:02:37.257: W/System.err(15487):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-06 17:02:37.257: W/System.err(15487):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
01-06 17:02:37.257: W/System.err(15487):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
01-06 17:02:37.257: W/System.err(15487):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing this error because the type Auth Token is bound to your account. You should try to implement "Cross-client Authorization", which will create a unique token according to the logged user in the application. You can read more information here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth